# Add record in method Seed with foreign key Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys, seed

I want add records with foreign keys, so as not to write the number id.

```
    protected override void Seed(ClockShopEntities context)
    { ... } // Seed

    private void AddType(ClockShopEntities context)
    {
        context.Typs.Add(new Typ { typName = "name1" });
        context.Typs.Add(new Typ { typName = "name2" });
    } // AddType

    private void AddCountry(ClockShopEntities context)
    {
        context.Countries.Add(new Country { countryName = "country1" });
        context.Countries.Add(new Country { countryName = "country2" });
        context.Countries.Add(new Country { countryName = "country3" });
        context.Countries.Add(new Country { countryName = "country4" });
    } // AddCountry
```

How can I add a value by specifying a name?

```
    // !!!!! with write id
    private void AddFabricator(ClockShopEntities context)
    {
        context.Fabricators.Add(new Fabricator { fName = "", idCountry = 1 });
    } // AddFabricator


    // How can I write without Id
    private void AddFabricator(ClockShopEntities context)
    {
        context.Fabricators.Add(
          new Fabricator { fName = "", idCountry = ?? where Country = "country1" });
    } // AddFabricator
```

I hope for help, Emma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot add by `Id` at this time as the `Country` has not yet been inserted in Database.** What you need to do instead is to set the `Country` property of `Fabricator` to the new `Country` being inserted and entity framework would itself take care of setting the `CountryId` on `Fabricator` when `Fabricator` is inserted in Database.

This code below should give you some idea:

```
private void AddCountry(ClockShopEntities context)
{
    var country1 = new Country { countryName = "country1" };
    AddFabricator(context, country1);
    context.Countries.Add(country1);

    context.Countries.Add(new Country { countryName = "country2" });
    context.Countries.Add(new Country { countryName = "country3" });
    context.Countries.Add(new Country { countryName = "country4" });
} // AddCountry

private void AddFabricator(ClockShopEntities context, Country country)
{
    context.Fabricators.Add(new Fabricator { fName = "", Country = country });
} // AddFabricator
```

Alternatively, you can also get the local Country (that has not yet been added) by name and assign that to `Country` property of `Fabricator`.

```
private void AddFabricator(ClockShopEntities context)
{
    context.Fabricators.Add(new Fabricator { fName = "", Country = context.Countries.First(c => c.countryName == "country1") });
} // AddFabricator
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to type 'bool'. Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type.

Comment: check the updated code, I had missed an equal sign in the condition.